# Backbone: TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined

Tags: node.js, backbone.js

I'm trying to load a json file into a Backbone Collection, but I keep running into a "TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined" error.

Specifically:

```
return Backbone.$.ajax.apply(Backbone.$, arguments);
TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined
```

Here is my script:

```
var Backbone = require('backbone');
var PostModel = Backbone.Model.extend();
var PostCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: PostModel,
    url: "data.json", 
    parse: function(data) {
    return JSON.parse(data);
    }
});

var posts = new PostCollection();
posts.fetch({reset: true});
posts.bind('reset', function () { console.log(posts); });
```

Is it because of async? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you run your code in nodejs environment instead browser then you could use [najax](https://github.com/najaxjs/najax) module to make requests

```
var Backbone = require('backbone'),
    najax = require('najax');

// set alias to najax
Backbone.ajax = najax;

var PostModel = Backbone.Model.extend();
var PostCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: PostModel,
    url: "data.json", 
    parse: function(data) {
       return JSON.parse(data);
    }
});

var posts = new PostCollection();
posts.fetch({reset: true});
posts.bind('reset', function () { console.log(posts); });
```

**EDIT**

If your `data.json` file in the same folder, as you pointed in comments, then you don't need to use `url` and `fetch`. You need to require your data first and then initialize your collection with them:

```
var Backbone = require('backbone'),
    data = require('./data.json');

var PostModel = Backbone.Model.extend();
var PostCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: PostModel,
    parse: function(data) {
       return JSON.parse(data);
    }
});

var posts = new PostCollection(data, {parse: true});
```

Comment: with this i get error:
`ssl = l.protocol.indexOf('https') === 0,
TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of null`

Comment: You need to provide absolute `url` to your source of data like `http://mysoure.com/data.json` instead `data.json` Note that protocol (http or https) is mandatory.

Comment: What if the json file lies in the same folder as the script? And not online anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that `Backbone.$.ajax` is `undefined` so you can't invoke it using `apply()`

Without seeing more code I can't say with certainty why that is but my educated guess is you're using something like Browserify or Webpack.

Until, I think, the most recent version of Backbone, Backbone.$ did not automatically reference jQuery or Zepto in commonJS (eg Node) environments--you have to attach it manually. Make sure you have jQuery installed and then try:

```
var Backbone = require('backbone')
var $ = require('jQuery');
Backbone.$ = $;
return Backbone.$.ajax.apply(Backbone.$, arguments);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem today, when trying to test jQuery & Backbone using a `npm test` file.

**Problem:** The `jQuery.ajax()` method is not a static function. So these don't exist at compile time in either the 1.x nor 2.x versions of jQuery: `function ajax()` nor `this.ajax: function()`. The `.ajax()` method is dynamically built at *initialization* time. It's created when jQuery loads into the DOM, but isn't available without a DOM. Since you are running Node.js, you have to mock up a fake DOM (global document & window objects) and then pass the window object into jQuery to create the $.ajax method. Then you can map that to Backbone's ajax method to make it work. The global document object is also required to allow jQuery to initialize.

This is the jQuery code which creates the dynamic `$.ajax()` method. I'm just pointing it out, so that you can see that it's dynamically built in this code:

```
jQuery.each( [ "get", "post" ], function( i, method ) {
    jQuery[ method ] = function( url, data, callback, type ) {

        // shift arguments if data argument was omitted
        if ( jQuery.isFunction( data ) ) {
            type = type || callback;
            callback = data;
            data = undefined;
        }

        // The url can be an options object (which then must have .url)
        return jQuery.ajax( jQuery.extend( {
            url: url,
            type: method,
            dataType: type,
            data: data,
            success: callback
        }, jQuery.isPlainObject( url ) && url ) );
    };
} );


jQuery._evalUrl = function( url ) {
    return jQuery.ajax( {
        url: url,

        // Make this explicit, since user can override this through ajaxSetup (#11264)
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "script",
        cache: true,
        async: false,
        global: false, // <- This 1.x line is removed from 2.x
        "throws": true
    } );
};
```

**Reason:** The unminified version of jQuery, mentions the following at the top of the file:

```
// For environments that do not have a `window` with a `document`
// (such as Node.js), expose a factory as module.exports.
// This accentuates the need for the creation of a real `window`.
// e.g. var jQuery = require("jquery")(window);
// See ticket #14549 for more info.
```

I found the same code documented at this NPM link, but I had a hard time getting their mock DOM code to work: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery#node

**Solution:** To fix your code, you may want to add this code, which was cobbled together from this jsdom GitHub link at:  https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom#how-it-works

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom").jsdom;

var markup = "<html><body></body></html>"; // Creates a default DOM.
var options = {}; // See: https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom#how-it-works

global.document = jsdom(markup, options); // Creates a document object from Node.
global.window = global.document.defaultView; // Creates a window object from Node.

// Passes the window object into jQuery, so that it can create the .ajax() method:
const $ = require("jquery")(global.window) 

// This maps the dynamic .ajax method into Backbone:
Backbone.$.ajax = $.ajax;
```

That should fix your Node.js code & NPM Tests and you'll be happily on your way! :-)